# Cannot add apt-key on Ubuntu in APT keyring : gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01) : gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof

Tags: apt, gnupg, keyrings

Here is what happens :

```bash
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 02D65EFF
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.gwHovf6GQe --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apandada1-brightness-controller.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/becrowdy-curl-backport.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/blahota-texstudio.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/fkrull-deadsnakes-python2_7.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/fossfreedom-libmtp.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/freetuxtv-freetuxtv-dev.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/gerardpuig-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/jonathonf-ffmpeg-3.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/jonathonf-ffmpeg-4.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/jonathonf-texlive.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/jonathonf-vim.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/jonathonf-vlc.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kwwette-octaves.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/me-tv-development-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mediaarea.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mozillateam-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/noobslab-apps.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/noobslab-themes.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/octave-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openlp-core-dev.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openlp-core-release.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/otto-kesselgulasch-gimp.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/palemoon_kovacsoltvideo.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/palemoon_opensuse.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/privoox-privoox.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pubring.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pypy-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/secring.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/stefanobalocco-multimedia.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/tigerite-bluez5.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/timchen119-bluez5-trusty.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/unit193-inxi.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/xapienz-curl34.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 02D65EFF
gpg: requesting key 02D65EFF from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof
gpg: key 02D65EFF: public key "Launchpad PPA for linrunner" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
$ sudo apt-get update 2>&1 | grep 02D65EFF
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2B3F92F902D65EFF
```

EDIT 1: If I try and refreshed the trusted keys, I also get these gpg warnings :

```bash
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg
rm: remove regular file ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg’? y
$ sudo apt-key update
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof
gpg: key 437D05B5: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof
gpg: key FBB75451: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof
gpg: key C0B21F32: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof
gpg: key EFE21092: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 4
gpg:               imported: 4  (RSA: 2)
```

EDIT 2: Maybe I have a broken/damaged gpg keyring :

```bash
$ apt-key list 2>&1 | grep -C3 gpg:
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/noobslab-themes.gpg
------------------------------------------
pub   1024R/F59EAE4D 2012-04-01
uid                 gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_search_next failed: invalid packet
 Launchpad PPA for NoobsLab

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openlp-core-release.gpg
```

I tried and removed those 2 files and then `apt-get update` but still, it does not work.

Comment: @Emmet No, it is not. I have tried `y-ppa-manager` and `launchpad-getkeys` but It is not working. See also my EDIT 1. Please reconsider

Comment: @Emmet My pb. seems happen when there is at least one damaged gpg keyring , than all the keyrings are not trusted. Please reconsider

Comment: @Emmet Please have a look at my EDIT2